# Babel: Which languages are supported (e.g. for Portugues)

Tags: babel

I read the Babel documentation and recognize that it supports several versions of Portuguese. According to the documentation I can specify additionally how e.g. the name of the `ToC`. The documentation mentions `\captions<lang>`. But with `portuguese` I try eg. `europeanportuguese`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,europeanportuguese]{article}
\usepackage[shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\addto\captionseuropeanportuguese{%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Conteúdo}
}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \kant[1]
    \section{Second chapter}
    \kant[2]
\end{document}
```

but this won't change the title of the ToC.

When I try `portuguese-portugal` then the situation is even worse! `\captionsportuguese-portugal` - won't be recognized and `lualatex` won't even compile.

And trying just simply `portuguese` I get

```
Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language 'nil' yet. \babel@toc {nil}{}
```

So, how do I define Portuguese properly - with either European and/or Brazil style?

Rem.: replacing the name of the lang with e.g. `naustrian` than the example works as expected.

Comment: Both `portuguese` and `brazilian` should work. The first for "European" Portuguese, use the one you prefer. I tested, and they work. Are you sure you changed the names in both places? (the option and the `\captions<language>`). There are also some old short aliases, but they sound awful for those who actually speak the language (`portuges` and `brazil`), and I think they are deprecated nowadays.

Comment: uhuh..... I tried now several times and now it works :-| I think the previous error I've got is due to some problems with the generation of the ToC :-/ Yes - I can confirm that `brazil` and `portuguese` are working. AND thx for the additional info about the wording - which sounds interesting ;-)

Comment: `brazil` is deprecated though, if that's what you want, better go with `brazilian`.

Comment: The name `europeanportuguese` is supported via `\babelprovide`. For the default styles, use, as indicated, `portuguese` or `brazilian`. To redefine captions, the recommended procedure is with `\setlocalecaption`.

Comment: Thx for clarification about the naming. Just as a side mark: In the document Version 3.94. I haven't read that `\captions<lang>` is deprecated or that `\setlocalecaption` should be used. And even when searching for `\setlocalecaption` I don't find a hint for "recommendation" - just as a feedback for the document. But anyway - thank you for pointing out.